# Cannot use command line Argument list too long

Tags: command-line, bash

I setup a 16.04 ubuntu webserver through AWS. After installing some programs now when I connect with putty it will not take any commands and after 20 seconds it starts repeatedly throwing the following errors-

```
-bash: /usr/bin/lesspipe: Argument list too long

-bash: /usr/bin/dircolors: Argument list too long
```

I can stop it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and I can change directories but that's it. Any suggestions to figure out whats causing this error? Sorry I'm relatively new to linux.

Comment: Seems like something bad got added to your shell files. Could you check your `.bashrc` and `.profile` files in your home folder?

Comment: Check for ^M at the end of lines -  Unix/Linux uses ^J, Windows uses ^M^J.

Comment: I've been following this setup guide to play around with open source crypto mining pool. https://github.com/ToastPool/yiimp#then-configure-the-web-app

Where I ran into this is after i almost completed the "configure and run Sia stratum server"

Comment: Those instructions appear to suggest (or could be interpreted to suggest) adding `source ~/.bashrc` to your `~/.bashrc` - this will make bash recursively source the file for ever.

Comment: Check what `getconf ARG_MAX` says. Your ARG_MAX value may be set too low, potentially in the /etc/limits.conf` file by the admin.  For current shell you could work around it with `ulimit -s <bytes>` , just need to know how much to set. A double what `ulimit -s` reports could be a start

Answer (score 5):

The instructions you linked say

> add the following to your ~/.bashrc
>
> ```
> export GOPATH=$HOME/.go 
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:$GOPATH/bin
>
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```

What the author presumably intended was

> add the following to your ~/.bashrc
>
> ```
> export GOPATH=$HOME/.go
> export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/go-1.10/bin:$GOPATH/bin
> ```
>
> *and then execute the command*
>
> ```
> source ~/.bashrc
> ```

If you actually add the line `source ~/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc`, then `bash` will hang for ever while it recursively sources the file - likely this is also what's causing the `argument list too long` errors as it will repeatedly add arguments to `lesspipe` and `dircolors`

To fix it you will need to edit `~/.bashrc` and remove the `source ~/.bashrc` line.

Answer (score 1):

Emmmmm just got the same error and fixed it.

First, `echo $PATH` in the command line then you got a long output of your environment variable. Copy part of it you really needed.

`export PATH=` + the path you copied.

Then everything is worked!

Don't forget to delete `source ~/.bashrc` at the end of .bashrc.

Comment: I had to ctrl-c the source as fast as possible so that I was not kicked out. After `export PATH= ` to include just the typical paths I was able to modify .bash_profile and re-source it without a problem

Answer (score 0):

All the above suggestions didn't work for me, the solution that I  found helpful is here,
Actually I screwed up my .bashrc file and then no command was working (`ls`, `vi`, `rm`, `mv`, literally nothing was working). Some people suggested to call vi editor using full path `/usr/bin/vi ~/.bashrc`, this was also not working for me. The solution that worked for me is to access your `.bashrc` file via the file browser.

Open the file browser, go to the home directory, press `Ctrl+H` so that hidden files are shown. Edit `.bashrc` as needed